# Dynamic menu not displaying in React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, menu

I am trying to display the dynamic menu from Laravel to react.

I am getting the data from sidebarDataFetcher API.

Below is my sideMenuSlice.ts. sideMenuSlice is set before fetching the data from the api.

here in console.log I am getting the empty array in
1.console.log(initialState);
empty is set to sideMenuSlice
2.console.log(sideMenuSlice);
and finally getting Data
3.console.log(sidebarData);

But I need to update the sideMenuSlice after the data is fetched from sidebarData. Any help is appreciated. Noob in React.

```
import SidebarDataFetcher from "../Pages/SidebarDataFetcher";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "./store";
import { icons } from "../base-components/Lucide";

export interface Menu {
  icon: keyof typeof icons;
  title: string;
  pathname?: string;
  subMenu?: Menu[];
  ignore?: boolean;
}

export interface SideMenuState {
  menu: Array<Menu | "divider">;
}

let initialState: SideMenuState = {
  menu: [],
};

(async () => {
  const sidebarData = await SidebarDataFetcher();
  console.log(sidebarData);
  initialState = {
    menu: Object.entries(sidebarData).flatMap(([key, value]) =>
      Object.entries(value).map(([subKey, subValue]) => ({
        icon: "Activity",
        title: subKey,
        subMenu: subValue.map((item) => ({
          icon: item.icon,
          title: item.name,
          pathname: item.url_slug,
        })),
      }))
    ),
  };

})();

console.log(initialState);
export const sideMenuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "sideMenu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
});

console.log(sideMenuSlice);

export const selectSideMenu = (state: RootState) => state.sideMenu.menu;
console.log(selectSideMenu);
export default sideMenuSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in laravel we used the fa icon and that icon is fetched directly from api and which is is used in react. In react we did not used fa icon that caused the issue.

Here is my code changes, I gave static icon and fixed.

```
(async () => {
  const sidebarData = await SidebarDataFetcher();
  console.log(sidebarData);
  initialState = {
    menu: Object.entries(sidebarData).flatMap(([key, value]) =>
      Object.entries(value).map(([subKey, subValue]) => ({
        icon: "Activity",
        title: subKey,
        subMenu: subValue.map((item) => ({
          icon: "Zap",   // here I gave the static icon, will fix in the form level as dynamic.
          title: item.name,
          pathname: item.url_slug,
        })),
      }))
    ),
  };

})();
```